# Get static files of dll assembly in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, plugins

i'm writing a web application (ASP.Net MVC 5 with C#) that is extensible with plugins. For this purpose i've written a small SDK which includes all interfaces the user has to implement for the plugin to load. That's working fine.

To write a plugin, the customer has to create a new Class Library Project in Visual Studio and import the SDK assembly.

Now i want to allow the user to pack static files with the plugin (which is currently just a dll). Those static files can be html, css, js, images, etc.
Those files have to be in a specific folder to get picked up by my server. At least, that's what i am planning to do. So on plugin install, i want to copy all files of a specific folder of the plugin to a plugin-specific folder of the server.

The question: How can i access those static files in an dll? I've read to use the GetManifestResourceNames method of the assembly but it's not working.

For testing, I'm doing this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginPath);
log.Debug("Number of ressources: " + assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Length);
foreach(var resName in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
   log.Debug(resName);
}
```

But the output is always "Number of ressources: 0" so GetManifestResourceNames returns an empty array.

I know the plugin is loaded correctly because i can access all it's classes and stuff. Am i doing something wrong? I'm quite new to C# because i am primary a Java developer.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a small test project and your code worked fine, listing the names of the resources correctly.

It's possible you're not adding the static files correctly.  When you add the static files to the project, ensure you change Build Action to be "Embedded Resource" in the properties window.

Comment: Thank you! That did it! It was set to "Content" instead of "Embedded Resource". Is there a way to define this build action for all static files and the output js-files of typescript-files?